# Passing State and Other Attributes at Login Using Microsoft.Identity.Web

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, microsoft.identity.web

I'm having troubles getting the .NET Core 6.0 authentication libraries working as I did with prior versions of .NET Framework.  Specifically, I'm using Microsoft.Identity.Web, but have not figured out how to get the scope and state parameters passed in and out that I want.  The signin-oidc keeps overriding these values with the ones I am trying to manage dynamically.  If I use the old method, which is just a RedirectResult to a properly formed URL for authentication, signin-oidc overrides the values I send in on the query string.  If I use the Challenge class with a list of name value pairs in the Properties collection (like state, consent, scope, etc), signin-oidc still overrides them.

I would like to have something as simple, readable, and operationally efficient as when I could just redirect to a URL with all the query string parameters, and provide a callback URL that had a "code", "error", "state", and other parameters in the method.  Right now I'm tied in knots over getting the right values over, and trying to get them back in a generic event override in the app's Program start up code.  Some stuff shows up in a generic Properties bag, but not in the logical "State" property of the context argument's ProtocolMessage.  What am I missing?

These are for cases where the user has authenticated to the site, and now I am trying to get them to consent and get a token for another Azure AD app.

Here is an example of using a simple redirect:
https://login.windows.net/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code%20id_token&client_id=aaaaaaaa-d4d2-4499-8e2a-b6957678fe80&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ffilemonweb%2Fhome%2FProcessCode&state=my%20state%20stuff&scope=openid%20offline_access%20api%3A%2F%2F1f43d4aa-d4d2-4499-8e2a-b6957678fe80%2F.default&response_mode=form_post&nonce=aee597a2-f050-48d0-9e3c-6c62f089b76c&prompt=consent

Here's an example using Challenge:

```
return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties(
new Dictionary<string, string?>() { { "state", "my state stuff" } },
new Dictionary<string, object?>() {
{ "client_id", ServiceConfig.Configuration.FILEMON_WEB_CLIENT_ID },
{ "type", "code%20id_token" },
{ "scope", "openid%20offline_access%20" + Uri.EscapeDataString(ServiceConfig.Configuration.FILEMON_WEB_SCOPE) },
{ "response_mode", "form_post" },
{ "nonce", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
{ "prompt", "consent"} })
{ RedirectUri = "filemonweb/home/tests" },         
"OpenIdConnect");
```

With the Edge dev tools network sniffer, I see that the request arrives as expected with the top example (properly formatted URL).  When the response is returned, I see it go to the redirect URI I requested, but the app sends a 302 response, and the response header includes a Location value that changes the redirect URI from the one I requested, to signin-oidc.  For example, like this:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=1f43d4aa-d4d2-4499-8e2a-b6957678fe80&redirect_uri=https://localhost/filemonweb/signin-oidc&response_type=code&scope=openid profile offline_access user.read&code_challenge=ZXiKTCHjJJZwo54YdulG7h45_9e4EOBnSv_kxNOTv2w&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637860882099818382.MDA0NGY1MGYtZWI0Ny00ZDU3LWJiMjQtZmE1ODk5ODdkYTEyYjQ0M2EzNjgtNzJjZi00ZjEyLWIxNTgtMGE2Y2JkYzc5YWE1&client_info=1&x-client-brkrver=IDWeb.1.16.0.0&state=CfDJ8MyJsY2aFrtOs5mEt79T88KiVV7RXqWFSO0rcSzX-NZcXlZ52qcIxpYLyz0wuWkqCh5vYPEg5Wj-YRUNMD542mvxJDGiKHz62k1hTctyvJxEtlIcZtbvLu1VOE9lNJdd6dKttBP2oi5nwDVZZC96-4bohWxxzfSk0-co8iet8xWhv8k0V2Iva1eatQ__LHOJofFQSV2IUHHmzokTB3s6reO4iLcGCyANYQWl9tp24IdQMWrwp3ZE4-DCDDQ1xzG5DZSbLAAyN29gOe5aAUwJBhmNIYX4Lm7fdsS9Bq9Xsh65h4E8Pff3U531KlDdY2WZK3gB-fyoML6rpT7DRQBN1Z5ls686pyMxtQRVN-LcQEYXCsmv7WZF3yiSQ-ctIN3X1GOehgTPJrSxpb8LxoT-Z9Bo_lQLEmwOvXw-9qbDzntv&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=6.12.1.0

When it sends that 302 response, it changes the State parameter, the Scope parameter, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: If possible, could you please share a code sample that you are trying at your end? It could help us better understand the issue. With only a description, it is hard to imagine what exactly you are doing at your side.

Comment: Sure, post has been edited to include both examples.  Thanks.